# AWS Internet Gateway can't see VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

In the AWS Command Console, I have two VPCs, as shown by the following screenshot:

[image: List of available VPCs]

But when I create a new Internet Gateway to allow outside traffic into this VPC, it seems that I can't find the VPC and I can only create a new one:

[image: Cannot select an existing VPC]

This is frustrating because the original, "stand-alone" way of creating a VPC allows me to put in public subnet I.P as well as availability zone and others, while the "Create VPC" option doesn't give me much. What mistake am I making here?

Comment: Do any of these VPCs have a internet gateway attached already?

Comment: That was it! I'm wondering: do you know if launching an EC2 instance *without* first having explicitly set a VPC also sets up a default VPC for that instance?

Comment: It would not setup a default VPC. Every region should already have this, if you delete it you would need to manually be recreated from the VPC console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This message will appear if your existing VPCs already have an internet gateway attached.

This happens because you can only have a single internet gateway attached to a VPC at once, although this error message does not make that clear.

> Only one internet gateway can be attached to a VPC at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your VPC might have been automatically configured with IGW. You can identify that by VPC ID. In the internet Gateway, you will see if that VPC ID is attached to an IGW. You simply need to detach that particular IGW from your VPC.